# error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token

Tags: c++

La idea es crear un simulador de precios de una concesionaria y que en base de la opcion elegida me dé el precio del auto.

Cuando intento compilarlo me salta un error en la línea 36 que es

> `error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token`

Ya intenté solucionarlo sin éxito y además para que inicie el programa tengo que pulsar un número del 1 a 3, de lo contrario me salta un error. Aquí el código:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int auto1;
int precio_t;
float precios[3]{4538900, 1211900, 2459900};
const float margen= 0.20;
std::string nombres[3]{"Mercedez Benz-AMG GT", "Mercedez Benz Clase E Coupe", "Mercedez Benz-AMG GT 4-Door Coupe"};
std::cin >> auto1;

cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t M E R C E D E Z  B E N Z" <<endl;
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t        Ver. 1.0.0";
cout << "\n\n\t puedes elegir entre estas opciones:" <<endl;
cout << "\n\t\t 1) Mercedez Benz-AMG GT" <<endl<<endl;
cout << "\n\t\t 2) Mercedez Benz Clase E Coupe" <<endl<<endl;
cout << "\n\t\t 3) Mercedez Benz-AMG GT 4-Door Coupe" <<endl<<endl;
cout << "\t Ingrese el numero del auto que selecciono: ";
cin >> auto1;

switch (auto1)
{
 case 1: cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto Mercedez Benz-AMG GT" <<endl<<endl;
    break;
    case 2: cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto Mercedez Benz Clase E Coupe" <<endl<<endl;
    break;
    case 3: cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto Mercedez Benz-AMG GT 4-Door Coupe" <<endl<<endl;
    break;
    default: cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha ingresado una opcion incorrecta" <<endl<<endl;
}

if (auto1 >= 0 && auto1 <= 2);
std::cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto: "<<nombres[auto1];
          << "\t El valor del auto que selecciono es de: " << precios[auto1];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A tu código le **sobra** el punto y coma (`;`) después de `<<nombres[auto1];`.

Answer (score 0):

El error principal que tienes es que has escrito:

```
std::cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto: "<<nombres[auto1];
          << "\t El valor del auto que selecciono es de: " << precios[auto1];
```

Me parece que te has olvidado añadir de nuevo `std::cout`.
También has puesto un punto y coma en lugar de abrir llaves. La solución completa se vería de la siguiente manera:

```
if (auto1 >= 0 && auto1 <= 2) {
   std::cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto: "<<nombres[auto1];
   std::cout << "\t El valor del auto que selecciono es de: " << precios[auto1];
}
```

Otro problema que yo veo según el código que muestras, estás controlando en un switch que auto1 pueda adquirir los valores 1, 2 o 3. En caso contrario, muestras un mensaje de error.

Sin embargo, en estas líneas de código:

```
if (auto1 >= 0 && auto1 <= 2);
std::cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto: "<<nombres[auto1];
          << "\t El valor del auto que selecciono es de: " << precios[auto1];
```

Como sabemos, los arrays empiezan en 0, es decir, si el usuario introduce un 3 tendremos problemas. Podría ser una buena idea codificarlo de modo que al valor que introduce el usuario le restes 1.